# Android: Textview shows not properly text (which contains bold and normal words)

Tags: android, textview

I have a simple TextView with span elements: just the first word is always in bold (the rest is in normal style). And **sometimes**, according the content, like we can see, the last character (on the first line in this example) doesn't show completely:

[image]

If I don't set the first world in bold, the text appears perfectly.

have you got some ideas guys? Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you add this and try: `android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Comment: Doesn't work @Andro

Answer (score 0):

you should give padding to your textView

```
<TextView
      .....
      android:padding="5dp"
      .....
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

@anthony give a right margin to text so that text doesn't get cut when style is set to bold.